# Формирование запроса SQL для вывода всего столбца

Tags: php, mysql

В массиве $user_data лежит только первое значение

```
$query= mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT login FROM Users") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
$user_data= mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Как сформировать запрос чтоб в массиве лежали все значения из login?

Comment: запрос менять не надо. mysqli_fetch_array получает одну строку. для получения всех или вызывайте ее в цикле или воспользуйтесь fetch_all http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже написал товарищ Mike, вам нужно использовать mysqli_fetch_all:

```
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```